# Horizontal scroll in android listView

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

I want to create list view, with ability to scrool horizontaly and vertically. 
Image shows row item from list view.
Everything should act as normal list view - ability to scroll verticaly.

Besides Title ( Teszt Elk Nev ) rest data in row should also scrool horizontaly. ( as you can see on image - second row ) 
When I scroll horizontaly all rows in list view should scrool horizontaly, so all rows has the same horizontaly scrool position.

[image]

I spent few hours try to solve it. Best solution so far is horizontal scrool only one row. 
My code for row item layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:text="one" />

    <com.example.testproject.CustomHorScroll
        android:id="@+id/myHorScroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/myLay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="70dp"
                android:text="two" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="70dp"
                android:text="three" />

            <!-- rest items goes here --!>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.example.testproject.CustomHorScroll>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to handle horizontal scrool movement and propagate to all row in listview to set horizontalscroolView.scrolBy(x,0). 
But I can't make it works. :/

Another idea is to skip listview and create custom layout with scroll view and horizontalScroll.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Android doesn't support scrolling items within scrolling items generally speaking.

Your best bet is probably to use something such as a ScrollView or a HorizontalScrollView, and a LinearLayout containing lists (or other scrollable items) inside of that: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into use the two way listview library.

https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view